# Compare array entries

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string-comparison

I need to compare array entries. I have two arrays with strings like `file1.csv`. These arrays are filled with almost the same but unsortet strings:

```
arrayA = {file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv ...}
arrayB = {file1.csv, file3.csv, fileABC.csv ...}
```

My approach was to loop through the arrays and compare the entries like

```
For i = LBound(arrayA) To UBound(arrayA)
    For j = LBound(arrayB) To UBound(arrayB)
        If arrayA(j) <> arrayB(i) Then
            ' call func
            i = i + 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
```

The idea is simple, take one variable `j` and hold the second `i`. Loop through both lists and only if one entry is missing, call a function. Here is the problem. My condition does not work for unsorted lists. Because `arrayA(2)` is equal to `arrayB(1)` but it triggers the *unequal* condition instant after one caparision is not equal. But that must first go through the complete array and only then decide whether an entry was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to loop through arrayA only or through both, but if just A then try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long
Dim arrayA As Variant: arrayA = Array("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv")
Dim arrayB As Variant: arrayB = Array("file1.csv", "file3.csv", "fileABC.csv")

For x = LBound(arrayA) To UBound(arrayA)
    If IsError(Application.Match(arrayA(x), arrayB, 0)) Then
        Debug.Print arrayA(x) & " Not Found"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

If you want to loop both, then maybe:

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
Dim arrayA As Variant: arrayA = Array("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv")
Dim arrayB As Variant: arrayB = Array("file1.csv", "file3.csv", "fileABC.csv")
Dim arrayC As Variant: arrayC = Array(arrayA, arrayB)

For x = 0 To 1
    y = ((x + 1) Mod 2)
    For z = LBound(arrayC(x)) To UBound(arrayC(x))
        If IsError(Application.Match(arrayC(x)(z), arrayC(y), 0)) Then
            Debug.Print arrayC(x)(z) & " Not Found"
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I just need `arrayA` compare to `arrayB`. So the first solution worked for me. Thanks!